# Frontend form database error with empty Users field

Tags: users, form, frontend

Within a frontend Add Product form (using Craft Commerce) I'm having problems with a database error whenever a Users field is left empty.

Here's the field:

```
{% set teachers = craft.users.group('teachers') %}
<select name="fields[teacher][]">
<option value="">n/a</option>
{% for teacher in teachers %}
  <option value="{{ teacher.id }}">{{ teacher.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

I've tried setting the empty value to zero, but no luck. The forms works fine apart from this, so I don't think it's anything specific to Craft Commerce.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. If you want to return an empty Users field, the field name attribute has to look like this:

```
<select name="fields[teacher]" value="">
```

But if you want to return a non-empty Users field, the name attribute is different:

```
<select name="fields[teacher][]" value="{user.id}">
```

So, I'm starting with the first example, and using an onChange event to switch the name attribute depending on whether the value is a valid user ID or not. Here's my final template code:

```
{% set teachers = craft.users.group('teachers') %}
<select class="ui search dropdown" name="fields[teacher]" id="teacherselect">
<option value="nA">n/a</option>
{% for teacher in teachers %}
  <option value="{{ teacher.id }}">{{ teacher.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

And the jquery if anyone wants it:

```
($(this).val() == "nA") ? $(this).attr('name', 'fields[teacher]') : $(this).attr('name', 'fields[teacher][]')
```

This works.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, seen this before. You can't just have an empty value like that because the validation stuff just sees it as a missing field that's required to not be missing. We got around it by adding the n/a value into the field itself in the back end of Craft.

Which doesn't help you for User Groups unless you want to create an 'n/a' group.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Have figured this out - the name attribute is different when the field is empty.